# Minimax Algorithm: Alpha-Beta Pruning Not Working

Tags: javascript, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I've been working on a web-based version of the board game Twist-Tac-Toe, a variation on Tic-Tac-Toe. The Minimax algorithm is working as expected, and it's very processing-intensive as expected. I've tried adding Alpha-Beta pruning to the code, but it appears to make the function evaluate a losing move as being equal to a tying move. So the computer makes some pretty dumb moves and I'm very stumped as to what the problem is with my code.

The function may be too big to post here, but here is the app with the alpha-beta pruning commented out:

http://ideonexus.github.io/Explorable-Explanations/games/twisttactoe/

here is the app with the alpha-beta pruning in place:

http://ideonexus.github.io/Explorable-Explanations/games/twisttactoe-alphabeta/

The entire recursiveMinimax function is 205 lines long, but I can post it here if that would be helpful. Any additional information I can provide, please let me know.